# Microsoft Excel: How to nest functions to return a certain value when within the parameters of the nested functions?

Tags: excel, nested-function

I have been messing with Microsoft Excel for many years for small things, and just recently got interested in upgrading a pre-made spreadsheet to calculate my net pay from all the deductions based off of the gross pay. I am specifically trying to calculate the amount of taxes being withheld for federal and state income taxes.
I want to nest (I believe the word is) multiple functions in a cell to calculate the taxes being withheld based on more than/less than parameters within another cell, with multiple parameters needed as to prevent me from having to go in and manually change them every time.
An example is: if gross (cell 927) is above $44, but lower than $224, withhold 10% return $4.4 in cell H23 (using $44, 10% of $44 is $4.4 and that result is returned into cell H23).

Here is important info you'll need to know:

1. The tax table is NOT an index, or anything included into the spreadsheet for `VLOOKUP` USE.
2. Currently the calculation is solely based on values I insert and quite simple. In cell h22(`=j22*.0123`) for example)
3. I don't wish to nor intend to add an index or table to the spreadsheet.
4. Federal Tax is cell H23, Gross Pay is cell J27. I wish to put the function within cell H23.

I have included a picture of the table I am trying to use with all the values I wish to use, and a picture of the specific cells from the document i wish to format the function with.

Your help is appreciated. Please don't be too harsh on me, as I am attempting to learn as much as possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.  Also, there is nothing in what you show to indicate which of the two tables you wish to use for your data.  And by excluding adding tables to your workbook, you are designing a worksheet that will be much more difficult to maintain in the future.

Comment: Yes, I have. I stated that the picture of the tax table contains the values i want to test for, and the value to calculate using the J27 cell in my spreadsheet. (so as i previously stated, if cell J27 is in between the ranges of $44 to $224, the function multiplies .10 by J27 and returns the result in H23. (The second picture posted was the spreadsheet cells)

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't want to mess up what I already have. after doing a quick search, i believe i am asking for help to compile an IF logic test which returns a calculated result in cell H23 when cell J27 is at or in between the values in each of those tiers of percentages as indicated on the tax table.

Comment: I would not bother using an `IF` statement as it will be much too cumbersome. Use VLOOKUP.  If you don't want to add a table to the worksheet, hard-code it within the formula. If you don't want to "mess up what you have", make a copy of what you have and work on the copy.  What country is that tax table for?

Comment: I am unsure of how to hard code a picture into a formula and have Excel look for the information within and return a calculated answer...

Comment: I don't know how to do that either.  Nor is it necessary.

Comment: Also, if that table is for US withholding, I don't see how you obtain 73.13 for Federal taxes.  There is information you are not applying

Comment: lol, well you suggested hard coding the table. I don't know where to find a table that I could hard code...even if i DID know how to hard code.

Now, I tried to use the IF function, and came out with this:
=IF(J27<44,J27>244, 0.1*J27), and it brings a calculation, but not the correct one because upon adding more arguments to evaluate and calculate, excel tells me there's too many arguments...

Comment: **HOW DID YOU OBTAIN $73.13?**

Comment: **IS THE TABLE FOR THE UNITED STATES?**

Comment: Yes, the table is for US withholding. The number you see in my sheet, is based off the percentage I used from figuring the percentage of my pay in each tax area that is withheld, based on my 40 hour work week NOT including overtime. it is also from the original simple formula i used to make the calculation and i didn't expect it to change, but i noticed that i go into a different tax bracket after overtime, so this prompted me to add a formula that includes the bracket percentages needed to calculate taxes all in one formula.

Comment: Hard coding the table means entering into the formula as an array.  This is NOT recommended, but since you have precluded putting it on your worksheet, it is an option.

Comment: So in the federal tax cell H23, the formula is a simple =J27*0.0706 (where 0.0706 is the number i got when i calculated the percentage of taxes being withheld @40h/w*$17.15.

Comment: OK, I understand your problem. To duplicate what your employer is doing, you will need to learn how to use and apply the withholding tax tables.  That is explained in IRS Publication 15 which you can download from (www.irs.gov).  Once you understand how to do that on paper, a SO or internet search for using tax tables in Excel should lead you to a solution.  The most flexible and easiest to maintain solution will have you enter a table onto your worksheet (probably manually).  You will then be able to edit this in years to come.

Comment: I know how to use the tax table, I just want Excel to take the gross, and if it meets any a certain criteria, return the proper calculation in the H23 cell reflecting the amount of taxes to be withdrawn. My main issue with importing a table is keeping the file small enough to email the file, if i need to. the file is almost too big to email as it is, and a table would throw that over the limit. I don't use dropbox, or cloud services like it for my own reasons, so i won't remotely entertain that idea.I really don't mind manually changing the information. I just need a working function.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed you didn't know that based on the algorithm you showed in a comment of `H23:= (gross income) x (percentage in the table)` which is incorrect. Please edit your question to show the **actual** formula you are using, along with the returned result and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate Federal Withholding Tax using the Percentage method (which is the design of the tax table you present:

- Add the appropriate tax table to your worksheet.

  - You don't write which one you are using.  I chose the Single Weekly table
  - Also, I used the table you showed in your question.  This is NOT the same as the one in IRS Publication 15, but the results of the computation are the same.
- Enter the number of exemptions you are claiming on your withholding.
- Compute your Net Salary
- Calculate Fed Tax withhold based on your Net Salary

When 2018 comes around, if the withholding changes due to changes in the tax table, or changes in the number of exemptions, or you get married, or whatever, it will be easy to edit the table and values in your worksheet.

So far as minimizing the size of your worksheet, I will leave that to you. That depends on why you are emailing this.  If it is just to send the results, you could send it as a `csv` file.

Use the formulas as shown below:

I `Name`'d the tax table `SingleWeekly` but you could use absolute references, if you preferred.

```
B5:  =Salary-Exemptions*B4

B8:  =Net_Salary*VLOOKUP(Net_Salary,SingleWeekly,2)- VLOOKUP(Net_Salary,SingleWeekly,3)
```

[image]

By the way, this could certainly be done as an `IF` statement with no table and no intermediate cells, but it would be much more difficult to maintain for any changes in the future.  In the formula below, the `77.9*2` represents the number of allowances you are claiming on your W2, and can be eliminated if you are claiming zero allowances.  Again, this refers to the Single Weekly table from your original post.

```
=IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=8090,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*39.6%-867.16,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=8058,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*35%-495.02,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=3730,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*33%-338.86,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=1812,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*28%-147.36,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=774, (Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*25%-93,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=224,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*15%-15.6,
IF((Gross_Salary-77.9*2)>=44,(Gross_Salary-77.9*2)*10%-4.4,0)))))))
```